# How to create image of datagrid and print it in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, printing

My project is built up with the mvvm pattern where I display items from my observablecollection in a datagrid. I have a Print button where I would like the datagrid to be printed on one or multiple pages (based on how many items the datagrid has) and split at a good position. I have tried creating an image of my datagrid with CreateBitmapFromVisual and then printing but the quality is descending with height of the image(>2000) and I can't get it on multiple pages.

I think that I could split the view in to multiple images and then stitch them together for printing but I don't know how to. Also getting a printpreview would be prefered.

Is this the way to go or is there another solution?